# Keep data from jquery getjson

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$.getJSON(fupurl, function(data) {
       ups = data[url+forup].shares;
        console.log(ups);
    });
$.getJSON(fdownurl, function(data) {
       downs = data[url+fordown].shares;
       if(!downs)
       downs = 0;
        console.log(downs);
    });
console.log(ups);
```

The above code it's inside of a function and variables downs and ups are defined before it.
I want to keep data inside those two variables to use it later.

Answer (score 1):

Make variables global:

```
var ups, downs;
$.getJSON(fupurl, function(data) {
       ups = data[url+forup].shares;
        console.log(ups);
    });
$.getJSON(fdownurl, function(data) {
       downs = data[url+fordown].shares;
       if(!downs)
       downs = 0;
        console.log(downs);
    });
console.log(ups);
```

Comment: sorry, yes, they global. But here you have deal with async. Try this, and you understand what it is: 
`var ups, downs; $.getJSON(fupurl, function(data) { ups = data[url+forup].shares; console.log(ups); console.log(new Date()); }); $.getJSON(fdownurl, function(data) { downs = data[url+fordown].shares; if(!downs) downs = 0; console.log(downs); console.log(new Date()); }); console.log(ups); console.log(new Date());`
Time after all ajax requests be less, then in ajax callbacks